# JS SQL output string or object

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I have this query

```
sql = client.query("SELECT * FROM monitormaterialsept", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
})
```

i dont know what the output of sql variable.

how to make it output JSON object?

Comment: You can make str to json using json parse. `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: you can't output like you should use xhr or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL 5.7 or later versions you can use

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(*your_fields*)) FROM monitormaterialsept
```

Comment: ty for the help sir.